# What method could I use to send a form text_field to my Rails controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two fields shown below that look like this on my website:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to implement an autocomplete function for the textfields. Now the Project Name text field works just fine but for my ticket I need to fix the broken Committer Name field which currently does not have the autocomplete feature.

The trick that I am facing is that it would seem that the Committer Name text_field is contingent upon whether the field in Project Name is entered or not. For example, by taking a look at the code, the Committer Name won't be able to execute autocomplete unless the Project Name has a project to look for. Here is the code for the view and controller.

```
%fieldset.row-fluid


.form-group
    %label.control-label.required= t('.project_name')
    .controls
      - value = params[:position].present? ? params[:position][:project_oss] : position.try(:project).try(:name)
      = f.text_field :project_oss, class: 'col-md-4 autocompletable', value: value,
      data: { source: '/autocompletes/project' }
      - error_tag(position, :project_oss)
      %p.help-block= t('.enter_openhub_project_name')

  .form-group
    %label.control-label= t('.committer_name')
    .controls
      = f.text_field :committer_name, class: 'col-md-4 autocompletable',
      data: { source: '/autocompletes/contributions' }
      - error_tag(position, :committer_name)
      %p.help-block
        = t('.enter_scm_committer_id')
        %br
        = t('.leave_this_blank')
```

Here is the controller code:

```
 class AutocompletesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_for_project, only: :contributions
  before_action :set_name_facts, only: :contributions

  def account
    accounts = params[:term].blank? ? [] : Account.simple_search(params[:term])
    render json: accounts.map { |a| { login: a.login, name: a.name, value: a.login, id: a.id } }
  end

  def project
    @projects = Project.not_deleted
                .where('lower(name) like ?', "%#{ (params[:term] || '').downcase }%")
                .where.not(id: params[:exclude_project_id].to_i)
                .order('length(name)')
                .limit(25)
  end

  def licenses
    licenses = params[:term] ? License.autocomplete(params[:term]) : []
    render text: licenses.map { |l| { nice_name: l.nice_name, id: l.id.to_s } }.to_json
  end

  def contributions
    render json: @name_facts.map { |nf| nf.name.name }
  end

  def tags
    tags = Tag.select(:name).autocomplete(params[:project_id], params[:term]).limit(10).map(&:name)
    render json: tags
  end

  private

  def set_name_facts
    @name_facts = NameFact.where(analysis_id: @project.best_analysis_id)
                  .where(['lower(names.name) like ? ', "%#{params[:term].strip.downcase}%"])
                  .includes(:name).references(:all).order('names.name ASC').limit(10)
  end

  def check_for_project
    project_name = params[:project].to_s.strip.downcase
    @project = Project.active.where(['lower(name) = ?', project_name]).first unless project_name.empty?
    render text: '' if @project.nil? || @project.best_analysis_id.nil?
  end
end
```

The problem is the before_action `:check_for_project`. In order for this to work, the `params[:project]` needs to be entered. However, it's always empty so the `render text:` portion is always implemented.

So here is what I need. Once a user enters a Project Name onto the first text_field, how can I capture that and that value and pass it in as `params[:project]` I know how to pass Rails controller variables to javascript but not the reverse. Does anyone have any ideas. Should I submit it automatically? That seems kind of complicated.

Comment: you need to send value of both fields to server in ajax. Where's the ajax code?